# How to configure cublas{t}symm() function arguments

Tags: cuda, multiplication, cublas, symmetric

This function performs the symmetric matrix-matrix multiplication using CUDA. Although, I succeeded in using the nonsymmetric version "cublas{t}gemm()" I couldn't use the "cublas{t}symm()" function properly.

I know that CUBLAS library uses column-major matrix storage. I am using row-major C/C++ matrix and I know how to solve this issue for "cublas{t}gemm()" by replacing the input matrices and etc. However, I couldn't solve it for the symmetric case. The problem is even if I use column-major matrix storage I find unexpectable results. Matrices contain complex floats (cuComplex). I assume I have row-major matrices. Here is the code and the output:

```
// Matrix multiplication: C = A * B.
// Host code.
//

// Utilities and system includes
#include <assert.h>
#include <helper_string.h>  // helper for shared functions common to CUDA SDK samples

// CUDA runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
#endif
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) ((a > b) ? a : b)
#endif

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// These are CUDA Helper functions (in addition to helper_cuda.h)

void inline checkError(cublasStatus_t status, const char *msg)
{
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%s", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
// end of CUDA Helper Functions

// Allocates a matrix with random float entries.
void randomCmplxInit(cuComplex *data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = make_cuComplex( rand() / (float)RAND_MAX, rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
}


//void initializeCUDA(int argc, char **argv, int &devID, int &iSizeMultiple, sMatrixSize &matrix_size)
void initializeCUDA(int argc, char **argv, int &devID)
{
    // By default, we use device 0, otherwise we override the device ID based on what is provided at the command line
    cudaError_t error;
    devID = 0;
    int m,n,k;

    if (checkCmdLineFlag(argc, (const char **)argv, "device"))
    {
        devID = getCmdLineArgumentInt(argc, (const char **)argv, "device");
        error = cudaSetDevice(devID);

        if (error != cudaSuccess)
        {
            printf("cudaSetDevice returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // get number of SMs on this GPU
    error = cudaGetDevice(&devID);
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID);

    printf("GPU Device %d: \"%s\" with compute capability %d.%d\n\n", devID, deviceProp.name, deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);

    // use a larger block size for Fermi and above
    int block_size = (deviceProp.major < 2) ? 16 : 32;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Run a simple test matrix multiply using CUBLAS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int matrixMultiply(int argc, char **argv, int devID)
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned int m,n,k; 
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaError_t error;

    error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID);

    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("cudaGetDeviceProperties returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // use a larger block size for Fermi and above
    int block_size = (deviceProp.major < 2) ? 16 : 32;

    m=3; //number of rows of matrix op(A) and C.  A--> (m x k)
    n=2; //number of columns of matrix op(B) and C. B--> (k x n)
    k=m; //number of columns of op(A) and rows of op(B). C--> (m x n)

    // I want to compute C = A*B in row-major format, 
    //so I must find C(T)=B(T)A(T) = C(T)A in column-major format 

    // allocate host memory for matrices A and B
    unsigned int size_A = m*(m+1)/2; //size of a symmetric matrix 
    unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_A;
    cuComplex *h_A = (cuComplex *)malloc(mem_size_A);

    unsigned int size_B = m*n;
    unsigned int mem_size_B = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_B;
    cuComplex *h_B = (cuComplex *)malloc(mem_size_B);

    // initialize host memory
    for (i = 0; i < size_A; ++i)
    h_A[i] = make_cuComplex( (float)(i+1),(float)0);

    for (i = 0; i < size_B; ++i)
    h_B[i] = make_cuComplex((float)(i+2), (float)0);

    // allocate device memory
    cuComplex *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    unsigned int size_C = m*n;
    unsigned int mem_size_C = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_C;

    // allocate host memory for the result
    cuComplex *h_C      = (cuComplex *) malloc(mem_size_C);
    cuComplex *h_CUBLAS = (cuComplex *) malloc(mem_size_C);

    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_A, mem_size_A);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_B, mem_size_B);

    // copy host memory to device
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, mem_size_B, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_C, mem_size_C);

    // setup execution parameters
    dim3 threads(block_size, block_size);
    dim3 grid(n / threads.x, m / threads.y);

    // create and start timer
    printf("Computing result using CUBLAS...");

    // CUBLAS version 2.0
    {
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        cublasStatus_t ret;

        ret = cublasCreate(&handle);

        if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cublasCreate returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        const cuComplex alpha = make_cuComplex(1.0f,0.0f);
        const cuComplex beta  = make_cuComplex(0.0f,0.0f);
        //Perform operation with cublas
        ret = cublasCsymm(handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_RIGHT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, n,m,&alpha,d_A,m,d_B,m,&beta,d_C,m);

        // copy result from device to host
        error = cudaMemcpy(h_CUBLAS, d_C, mem_size_C, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        checkError(cublasDestroy(handle), "cublasDestroy() error!\n");
    }


    printf ("\nComputations completed.\n\n");

    printf (" symm matrix A: \n");
    int s=0;
    for (i=0; i<min(m,4); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        //printf ("%7.5G + j(%7.5G)", h_A[j+i*k].x,h_A[j+i*k].y);
        printf ("%7.5G", h_A[s].x); 
        s++;
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n matrix B: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(k,4); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<min(n,4); j++) {
        //printf ("%7.5G + j(%7.5G)", h_B[j+i*n].x,h_B[j+i*n].y);
          printf ("%7.5G", h_B[j+i*n].x);
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n matrix C=A*B: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(m,4); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<min(n,4); j++) {
        //printf ("%7.5G + j(%7.5G)", h_CUBLAS[j+i*n].x,h_CUBLAS[j+i*n].y);
          printf ("%7.5G", h_CUBLAS[j+i*n].x);
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }

    // clean up memory
    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);
    //free(reference);
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);

    cudaDeviceReset();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("[Matrix Multiply CUBLAS] - Starting...\n");
    int devID = 0, sizeMult = 5;
    initializeCUDA(argc, argv, devID);
    int matrix_result = matrixMultiply(argc, argv, devID);
}
```

I suppose that I have the following matrices for the multiplication:

A =

```
1     2     4
2     3     5
4     5     6
```

B =

```
 2     3
 4     5
 6     7
```

and expect to obtain

A*B =

```
34    41
46    56
64    79
```

But the obtained **OUTPUT** is as follows:

```
symm matrix A:    
     1     
     2     3
     4     5     6

matrix B:
     2     3
     4     5
     6     7

matrix C=A*B:
    78    90
    74    97
    114    146
```

What am I missing in this code ? Probably the arguments of "cublasCsymm" function are wrong.

Thanks,
Kagan

Comment: Could you please post a fully compilable code instead of a snippet?

Comment: Both the expected results as well as the obtained results seem wrong to me. Can you recheck the values you are showing here ?

Comment: I have checked the expected results and included the entire code. I have also changed the code (I suppose) such that it operates on row-major matrices. I obtained this code by editing Nvidia CUDA's matrix multiplication sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Based on questions posed below, I elected to re-work my answer and example code.
You *can* handle row-major storage without transpose at least for these operations.  And this observation is further facilitated by the fact that the `symm` function does not used the packed storage.

So to answer the additional questions:

1. the `cublasCsymm` function does not use a packed storage format (like some other functions such as [cublasCspmv](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-spmv) for example),  because the `cublasCsymm` function is intended to duplicate the functionality of the corresponding [netlib function](http://www.netlib.org/blas/csymm.f), which also does not use a packed storage format.  Based on my review of the cublas API, I don't see a symmetric-packed-storage matrix-matrix multiply function available.
2. You *can* use row-major storage (e.g. C-style) with cublas, without transposing, at least for these operations (matrix-matrix multiply, without packed storage) by following the advice given [here](http://peterwittek.com/2013/06/cublas-matrix-c-style/).

What follows is a re-worked version of my previous example, that incorporates the information in item 2 above.

```
// Matrix multiplication: C = A * B.
// Host code.
//

// Utilities and system includes
#include <assert.h>
#include <helper_string.h>  // helper for shared functions common to CUDA SDK sa
mples

// CUDA runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

// error check macros
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// for CUBLAS V2 API
#define cublasCheckErrors(fn) \
    do { \
        cublasStatus_t __err = fn; \
        if (__err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal cublas error: %d (at %s:%d)\n", \
                (int)(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)



#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
#endif
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) ((a > b) ? a : b)
#endif

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// These are CUDA Helper functions (in addition to helper_cuda.h)

void inline checkError(cublasStatus_t status, const char *msg)
{
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%s", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
// end of CUDA Helper Functions

// Allocates a matrix with random float entries.
void randomCmplxInit(cuComplex *data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = make_cuComplex( rand() / (float)RAND_MAX, rand() / (float)RAND
_MAX);
}


//void initializeCUDA(int argc, char **argv, int &devID, int &iSizeMultiple, sMa
trixSize &matrix_size)
void initializeCUDA(int argc, char **argv, int &devID)
{
    // By default, we use device 0, otherwise we override the device ID based on
 what is provided at the command line
    cudaError_t error;
    devID = 0;

    if (checkCmdLineFlag(argc, (const char **)argv, "device"))
    {
        devID = getCmdLineArgumentInt(argc, (const char **)argv, "device");
        error = cudaSetDevice(devID);

        if (error != cudaSuccess)
        {
            printf("cudaSetDevice returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __
LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // get number of SMs on this GPU
    error = cudaGetDevice(&devID);
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID);

    printf("GPU Device %d: \"%s\" with compute capability %d.%d\n\n", devID, dev
iceProp.name, deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);

}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Run a simple test matrix multiply using CUBLAS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int matrixMultiply(int argc, char **argv, int devID)
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned int m,n,k;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaError_t error;

    error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID);

    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("cudaGetDeviceProperties returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // use a larger block size for Fermi and above

    m=3; //number of rows of matrix op(A) and C.  A--> (m x k)
    n=2; //number of columns of matrix op(B) and C. B--> (k x n)
    k=m; //number of columns of op(A) and rows of op(B). C--> (m x n)

    // I want to compute C = A*B in row-major format,
    //so I must find C(T)=B(T)A(T) = C(T)A in column-major format

    // allocate host memory for matrices A and B
    unsigned int size_A = m*m; //size of a symmetric matrix
    printf("size_A = %d\n", size_A);
    unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_A;
    cuComplex *h_A = (cuComplex *)malloc(mem_size_A);

    unsigned int size_B = m*n;
    unsigned int mem_size_B = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_B;
    cuComplex *h_B = (cuComplex *)malloc(mem_size_B);

    // initialize host memory
//    for (i = 0; i < size_A; ++i)
//    h_A[i] = make_cuComplex( (float)(i+1),(float)0);
    h_A[0] = make_cuComplex((float)1, (float)0);
    h_A[1] = make_cuComplex((float)2, (float)0);
    h_A[2] = make_cuComplex((float)4, (float)0);
    h_A[3] = make_cuComplex((float)0, (float)0);
    h_A[4] = make_cuComplex((float)3, (float)0);
    h_A[5] = make_cuComplex((float)5, (float)0);
    h_A[6] = make_cuComplex((float)0, (float)0);
    h_A[7] = make_cuComplex((float)0, (float)0);
    h_A[8] = make_cuComplex((float)6, (float)0);

//    for (i = 0; i < size_B; ++i)
//    h_B[i] = make_cuComplex((float)(i+2), (float)0);
    h_B[0] = make_cuComplex((float)2, (float)0);
    h_B[1] = make_cuComplex((float)3, (float)0);
    h_B[2] = make_cuComplex((float)4, (float)0);
    h_B[3] = make_cuComplex((float)5, (float)0);
    h_B[4] = make_cuComplex((float)6, (float)0);
    h_B[5] = make_cuComplex((float)7, (float)0);

    // allocate device memory
    cuComplex *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    unsigned int size_C = m*n;
    unsigned int mem_size_C = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_C;

    // allocate host memory for the result
    cuComplex *h_C      = (cuComplex *) malloc(mem_size_C);
    cuComplex *h_CUBLAS = (cuComplex *) malloc(mem_size_C);

    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_A, mem_size_A);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_B, mem_size_B);

    // copy host memory to device
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, mem_size_B, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_C, mem_size_C);


    // create and start timer
    printf("Computing result using CUBLAS...");

    // CUBLAS version 2.0
    {
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        cublasStatus_t ret;

        ret = cublasCreate(&handle);

        if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cublasCreate returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        const cuComplex alpha = make_cuComplex(1.0f,0.0f);
        const cuComplex beta  = make_cuComplex(0.0f,0.0f);
        //Perform operation with cublas
        ret = cublasCsymm(handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_RIGHT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, n,m,&alpha,d_A,m,d_B,n,&beta,d_C,n);

        if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cublasCsymm returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // copy result from device to host
        error = cudaMemcpy(h_CUBLAS, d_C, mem_size_C, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        checkError(cublasDestroy(handle), "cublasDestroy() error!\n");
    }


    printf ("\nComputations completed.\n\n");

    printf (" symm matrix A: \n");
//    int s=0;
    for (i=0; i<min(m,4); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<min(m,4); j++) {
        //printf ("%7.5G + j(%7.5G)", h_A[j+i*k].x,h_A[j+i*k].y);
//        printf ("%7.5G", h_A[s].x);
        printf ("%7.5G", h_A[j+(i*m)].x);
//        s++;
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n matrix B: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(k,4); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<min(n,4); j++) {
        //printf ("%7.5G + j(%7.5G)", h_B[j+i*n].x,h_B[j+i*n].y);
          printf ("%7.5G", h_B[j+(i*n)].x);
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }

    printf ("\n matrix C=A*B: \n");
    for (i=0; i<min(m,4); i++) {
      for (j=0; j<min(n,4); j++) {
        //printf ("%7.5G + j(%7.5G)", h_CUBLAS[j+i*n].x,h_CUBLAS[j+i*n].y);
          printf ("%7.5G", h_CUBLAS[j+(i*n)].x);
      }
      printf ("\n");
    }

    // clean up memory
    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);
    //free(reference);
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("[Matrix Multiply CUBLAS] - Starting...\n");
    int devID = 0;
    initializeCUDA(argc, argv, devID);
    int matrix_result = matrixMultiply(argc, argv, devID);
    cudaCheckErrors("some error");
    return 0;
}
$ ./t213
[Matrix Multiply CUBLAS] - Starting...
GPU Device 0: "Tesla M2070" with compute capability 2.0

size_A = 9
Computing result using CUBLAS...
Computations completed.

 symm matrix A:
      1      2      4
      0      3      5
      0      0      6

 matrix B:
      2      3
      4      5
      6      7

 matrix C=A*B:
     34     41
     46     56
     64     79
$
```

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:

Several problems:

- When I run your code as you have it posted right now, I don't get the
  results that you show.  Here's what I get:

  ```
  [Matrix Multiply CUBLAS] - Starting...
  GPU Device 0: "Tesla M2070" with compute capability 2.0

  Computing result using CUBLAS...
  Computations completed.

  symm matrix A:
    1
    2      3
    4      5      6

  matrix B:
    2      3
    4      5
    6      7

  matrix C=A*B:
    -131   -128
     260   -122
    -115    266
  ```

The code compiles with a number of warnings and also you're not doing proper error checking (for example you're not checking the return value from `cublasCsymm`

- You are wanting to multiply C = A*B  This means A is on the *LEFT*,
  but you are passing `CUBLAS_SIDE_RIGHT` to `cublasCsymm`  Several other `cublasCsymm` parameters were wrong as well.  I think maybe you thought you could do `A*B` as (B(T)*A(T)) but that only works for square matrices.  Not sure what you were thinking, exactly.
- You having row-major storage on your matrices and passing them to cublas which interprets them in column-major order.  For the following matrix:

  ```
  1 2
  3 4
  ```

row-major storage looks like this:

```
    1 2 3 4
```

column-major storage looks like this:

```
    1 3 2 4
```

You can transpose these matrices if you wish, using `cublasCgeam` or you can manually modify your storage.

- You're making some sort of assumption about some kind of compressed
  storage format for the symmetric matrix `A` which is not correct. 
  Read carefully the defintion of the [storage
  type](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasfillmode_t).
  It doesn't say the portion of the matrix that is "supplied" or
  "present" it says the portion of the matrix that is *filled*.

Here is a complete code that has the above problems fixed:

```
// Matrix multiplication: C = A * B.
// Host code.
//

// Utilities and system includes
#include <assert.h>
#include <helper_string.h>  // helper for shared functions common to CUDA SDK sa
mples

// CUDA runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

// error check macros
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// for CUBLAS V2 API
#define cublasCheckErrors(fn) \
    do { \
        cublasStatus_t __err = fn; \
        if (__err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal cublas error: %d (at %s:%d)\n", \
                (int)(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)



#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
#endif
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) ((a > b) ? a : b)
#endif

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// These are CUDA Helper functions (in addition to helper_cuda.h)


void inline checkError(cublasStatus_t status, const char *msg)
{
    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%s", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
// end of CUDA Helper Functions

// Allocates a matrix with random float entries.
void randomCmplxInit(cuComplex *data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = make_cuComplex( rand() / (float)RAND_MAX, rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
}


//void initializeCUDA(int argc, char **argv, int &devID, int &iSizeMultiple, sMatrixSize &matrix_size)
void initializeCUDA(int argc, char **argv, int &devID)
{
    // By default, we use device 0, otherwise we override the device ID based on what is provided at the command line
    cudaError_t error;
    devID = 0;

    if (checkCmdLineFlag(argc, (const char **)argv, "device"))
    {
        devID = getCmdLineArgumentInt(argc, (const char **)argv, "device");
        error = cudaSetDevice(devID);

        if (error != cudaSuccess)
        {
            printf("cudaSetDevice returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // get number of SMs on this GPU
    error = cudaGetDevice(&devID);
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID);

    printf("GPU Device %d: \"%s\" with compute capability %d.%d\n\n", devID, deviceProp.name, deviceProp.major, deviceProp.minor);

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Run a simple test matrix multiply using CUBLAS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int matrixMultiply(int argc, char **argv, int devID)
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned int m,n,k;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaError_t error;

    error = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, devID);

    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("cudaGetDeviceProperties returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", error, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // use a larger block size for Fermi and above

    m=3; //number of rows of matrix op(A) and C.  A--> (m x k)
    n=2; //number of columns of matrix op(B) and C. B--> (k x n)
    k=m; //number of columns of op(A) and rows of op(B). C--> (m x n)

    // I want to compute C = A*B in row-major format,
    //so I must find C(T)=B(T)A(T) = C(T)A in column-major format

    // allocate host memory for matrices A and B
    unsigned int size_A = m*m; //size of a symmetric matrix
    printf("size_A = %d\n", size_A);
    unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_A;
    cuComplex *h_A = (cuComplex *)malloc(mem_size_A);

    unsigned int size_B = m*n;
    unsigned int mem_size_B = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_B;
    cuComplex *h_B = (cuComplex *)malloc(mem_size_B);

    // initialize host memory
//    for (i = 0; i < size_A; ++i)
//    h_A[i] = make_cuComplex( (float)(i+1),(float)0);
    h_A[0] = make_cuComplex((float)1, (float)0);
    h_A[1] = make_cuComplex((float)2, (float)0);
    h_A[2] = make_cuComplex((float)4, (float)0);
    h_A[3] = make_cuComplex((float)0, (float)0);
    h_A[4] = make_cuComplex((float)3, (float)0);
    h_A[5] = make_cuComplex((float)5, (float)0);
    h_A[6] = make_cuComplex((float)0, (float)0);
    h_A[7] = make_cuComplex((float)0, (float)0);
    h_A[8] = make_cuComplex((float)6, (float)0);

//    for (i = 0; i < size_B; ++i)
//    h_B[i] = make_cuComplex((float)(i+2), (float)0);
    h_B[0] = make_cuComplex((float)2, (float)0);
    h_B[1] = make_cuComplex((float)4, (float)0);
    h_B[2] = make_cuComplex((float)6, (float)0);
    h_B[3] = make_cuComplex((float)3, (float)0);
    h_B[4] = make_cuComplex((float)5, (float)0);
    h_B[5] = make_cuComplex((float)7, (float)0);

    // allocate device memory
    cuComplex *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    unsigned int size_C = m*n;
    unsigned int mem_size_C = sizeof(cuComplex) * size_C;

    // allocate host memory for the result
    cuComplex *h_C      = (cuComplex *) malloc(mem_size_C);
    cuComplex *h_CUBLAS = (cuComplex *) malloc(mem_size_C);

    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_A, mem_size_A);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_B, mem_size_B);

    // copy host memory to device
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    error = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, mem_size_B, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **) &d_C, mem_size_C);


    // create and start timer
    printf("Computing result using CUBLAS...");

    // CUBLAS version 2.0
    {
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        cublasStatus_t ret;

        ret = cublasCreate(&handle);

        if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cublasCreate returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        const cuComplex alpha = make_cuComplex(1.0f,0.0f);
        const cuComplex beta  = make_cuComplex(0.0f,0.0f);
        //Perform operation with cublas
        ret = cublasCsymm(handle, CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, m,n,&alpha,d_A,m,d_B,m,&beta,d_C,m);
        if (ret != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("cublasCsymm returned error code %d, line(%d)\n", ret, __LINE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

Here is the output:

```
[Matrix Multiply CUBLAS] - Starting...
GPU Device 0: "Tesla M2070" with compute capability 2.0

size_A = 9
Computing result using CUBLAS...
Computations completed.

 symm matrix A:
      1      0      0
      2      3      0
      4      5      6

 matrix B:
      2      3
      4      5
      6      7

 matrix C=A*B:
     34     41
     46     56
     64     79
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.However,I still have two problems to be solved.First,it seems meaningless to me to write down 0s for matrix A.Why would I want to fill the memory with such invaluable data?I thought the advantage of cublasCsymm was to accept symmetric matrices in packed form as in [Packed Storage](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node123.html).Otherwise why would I want to use this function,I couldn't get this?Secondly,I need to use row-major matrices for compatibility with an old project and I dont want to transpose them because the matrices are really  large.Is there any way?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer to either of these issues. My suggestion is to post them as new questions on SO so they get more visibility.

Comment: There are some cublas functions that work on symmetric matrices stored in packed format.  `spmv` and `tpmv` are examples.  With those you see that the [function docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-spmv) call out the matrix as stored in packed format and define the packed storage format.  `symm` is not one of these and I don't see a packed-symmetric-matrix  matrix multiply in the list of available functions.  And I don't know how to use [cublas with row-major data](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#data-layout) unless you do some sort of transpose.

Comment: This [method](http://peterwittek.com/2013/06/cublas-matrix-c-style/) may help you do cublas-style matrix multiplication on matrices stored in row-major format.  I don't know that this could be extended to packed storage format, but the `symm` function does not used packed storage format.

Comment: Yes, this method is how I actually use the gemm function. I think I need ask this issue as a new question as you suggested. Thanks.